# Remove files using QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I want to remove all .exe files before compiling a make file. I used the following lines to do that but it doesn't  work. What is the problem with QProcess? Is there any other solution to this? Please help.

```
 QProcess del;
 del.start("rm", QStringList() << outputPath + "/" + "*.exe");  //Removing all .exe files in outputPath.
 del.waitForFinished(-1);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is possible to cleanup output in most IDE-s
2. It is possible to create pre-build events
3. It is not possible to delete executables that are running (win plaform)
4. Why you don't use QFile::remove?
5. In windows you should use backslash \ instead of slash / to as path separator

Comment: I work on a linux platform. I have tried QFile::remove and it didn't work for me